# Bug with tax calculation and discount price

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, tax

[image: Bug with tax calculation and discount price]

Hello,

After reading a lot of threads about problem with tax calculation with discount price I found no solution about what is happening to me.

As you can see in the screenshot joined the price total after discount is different between the 3 products. This is a 30% discount on each products. The first and the last seems good but the second one has a different total. I don't know why. 
Thanks for your help !

EDIT :

Add a screenshot of my tax configuration settings

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your settings under system->configuration->tax settings?

Comment: try and set `Tax Calculation Method Based On` to `unit price` instead of `Total`

Answer (score 1):

**Issue**: 
The result of tax is a bit more than being expected when the tax setting is as follows in system->configuration->tax settings

> Tax Calculation Method Based On: Unit Price 
>   Apply Customer Tax: After Discount

**Resolution**:
I rewrite the method **_calcUnitTaxAmount** in model Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax

It was:

```
$discountRate = ($unitTax/$price) * 100;<br/>
$baseDiscountRate = ($baseUnitTax/$basePrice) * 100;
```

After rewrite, it is

```
$discountRate = $inclTax == 1 ? ($unitTax/($price - $unitTax)) * 100 : ($unitTax/$price) * 100;<br/>
$baseDiscountRate = $inclTax == 1 ? ($baseUnitTax/($basePrice - $baseUnitTax)) * 100 : ($baseUnitTax/$basePrice) * 100;
```

Then the result in the totals is correct.

Comment: can you please explain in term of tax have to be calculate in magento store

Comment: The first level tax calculation is **Tax Calculation Method Based On** which includes CALC_UNIT_BASE, CALC_ROW_BASE, CALC_TOTAL_BASE. Then the process of calculation goes into seperately. <br/> In CALC_UNIT_BASE, it does another level calculation by Apply Customer Tax: Before Discount / After discount. The bugs happens in After discount.

Comment: you can also see the details and view point :http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configuration-sales-tax-calculation-settings

Comment: Cool Thanks, It needs more time to figure the tax calculation out clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In magento 1.8.1 are lots of rounding issues fixed (there are still a lot) so you should try making an update.